# Do I need the web.config values configuration -> runtime -> assemblyBinding for System.Web.Extensions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Do I need the web.config values configuration -> runtime -> assemblyBinding for System.Web.Extensions? I'm pretty sure they're autobuilt by the VS2010 new project rules, but I'm not entirely sure what circumstance they are needed under.

Please note, I am pretty sure I understand what it's used *for*, I just want to know if I should be able to safely remove them if I know that my server will be IIS7 and Win2k8 or later.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v2.0.50727">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can remove them if you like, all these entries ensure there is no conflicts or the wrong assembly being loaded the loader will load the 3.5.0.0 version.

If you can ensure that your solution and servers wont have this problem then there should be no problem.